# Dual problem of unconstrained linear least squares

Tags: convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, least-squares, duality-theorems, karush-kuhn-tucker

The following seemingly simple question is confusing the heck out of me:

> Take the least squares regression problem (for $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n×p}$ and $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$):
>
> $$\min_{\beta \in \mathbb{R}^p} \| y-X\beta \|_2^2$$
>
> Prove that the equivalent dual of this problem is:
>
> $$\min_{v \in \mathbb{R}^n} \| y-v \|_2^2 \text{ subject to } X^T v = 0$$
>
> **Hint:** In deriving the dual, you may start by introducing the auxiliary variable $z=X\beta$.

(Source: Q2.b in [http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~ryantibs/convexopt/homework/homework3.pdf](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/%7Eryantibs/convexopt/homework/homework3.pdf))

**What I tried**

Following the hint, of course, I get the Lagrangian:

$$L(\beta,z,v) = \lVert y - z \rVert_2^2 + v^T(z-X\beta)$$

Since this function is convex, we can take the gradient to find the point where it minimizes $L$ as a function of $z$ and $\beta$. Doing that gives us the following two conditions:

$$ -2(y-z) + v = 0 $$
$$ -X^T v = 0 $$

Plugging that back into the Lagrangian, I get:

$$ g(v) = \frac14 \lVert v \rVert^2 + v^T (y - \frac12 v) = v^T (y - \frac14 v) $$

And we have the constraint $X^Tv = 0$ as desired. However, while maximizing this $g(v)$ is *equivalent* to minimizing $\lVert y - v \rVert_2^2$, in that the same $v^\ast$ should optimize both, the two functions are not equal and should not have the same optimal value $g(v^\ast)$.

The second part of the question asks about the relationship between the primal and dual solutions, so I'm not sure how to proceed, given that I didn't find the two problems to be primal and dual. Did I make a mistake in the math, or is there something I'm missing about this question?

Comment: You're right. The dual should be a maximization, and its optimal objective value should be identical to the optimal objective value of the primal. There are important practical and theoretical reasons why we define duals this way.  Prof. Tibschirani is no slouch, though, so I'm going to guess his defense hinges on the claim that it is an _equivalent_ dual. I don't agree with his wording there, personally.

Comment: Thanks, Michael. I should have probably quoted the second part of the question as well: "What is the relationship between the primal and the dual solutions, implied by the KKT conditions? Explain why this relationship makes sense, given what you know about projections onto linear subspaces." 

If we define $h(v) = \| y - v \|_2^2$ and $f(\beta)$, $g(v)$ as above, then we have the relationship $f(\beta^\ast) = g(v^\ast) = y^Ty - h(v^\ast)$ but I'm not sure if that answers the question as posed. It's a tough one.

Answer (score 1):

Think of this geometrically. Say $n>p$. The primal $\beta$ are the coefficients of the linear combination of columns of $X$ that is closest to $y$. The dual $\nu$ is the error vector. We want the error vector to be orthogonal to the columns of $X$, which is expressed by the constraint $X^T \nu = 0$.

Comment: If $v$ is the error, wouldn't the dual be to minimize $v$ itself?

Comment: $y = X\beta + \nu$, where $\nu \perp X_{:,1}, X_{:,2} \dots$ is the error vector. The primal problem asks to minimize $||\nu||_2^2$, the dual problem asks to maximize $||y-\nu||$. Both are equivalent.

Comment: What you're saying makes sense to me, logically. However, the homework question is asking to prove that the dual is *minimize* $\| y - v \|$. What it feels like to me (but I can't show) is that $v$ is some orthogonal component of the error, that is inverse to the error in $y - X\beta$.

Comment: As Michael pointed out, I think the min is a typo. The dual of a minimization problem is a maximization problem.

Comment: I don't think that's a typo actually. Let's take a quick example: $y = \binom{0}{1}$ and $X = \binom{1}{1}$. Since $X^Tv=0$ we must have $v = \binom{a}{-a}$. Then $\|y-v\|^2=(-a)^2+(1+a)^2=2a^2+2a+1$ which is unbounded from above. Minimization is indeed what we're looking for here.

Comment: You're right, my earlier comment is wrong - I missed the negative sign. The dual is to maximize $v^T(y-\tfrac{1}{2}v)$ which as you pointed out in the answer, is equivalent to minimizing $||y-v||^2$. The geometric interpretation still applies though as your example shows. The objective in the dual problem is to find a vector orthogonal to the columns of $X$ that minimizes $||y-v||$. Here's another way to look: Let $y-v=s$, the dual problem then becomes $\min_s ||s||^2$ subject to $X^T s = X^T y$, which is of the form $\min_x ||x||$ subject to $Ax=b$.